# How to insert records in a table from another table in ascending order

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by, sql-insert

I not able to insert a records in SQL server table from another table in same databse in ascending order.

```
INSERT into SalaryDetails.dbo.SalaryAsc
SELECT *
FROM SalaryDetails.dbo.Salary as tb1
order by tb1.id
```

Below is what I am fetching:

Expected

[image: the id bvalues should be in ascending order]

Obtained:

[image: But got the id values in random order]

Comment: Without explicit ORDER BY in SELECT statement there is no such  thing as ordered table

Comment: Since SQL represent unordered sets.

Comment: The OP does have an `ORDER BY` @LukaszSzozda.

Comment: @Larnu `SELECT ... FROM ... ORDER BY` when data is fetched for second image. I am not thinking of ORDER BY in `INSERT INTO SELECT`. Plus clustered index on `id` does not change anything.

Comment: Need to see your schema

Comment: Yes, and the OP has `INSERT INTO...SELECT...FROM...ORDER BY...` @LukaszSzozda They are using an `ORDER BY` to **`INSERT`** the data.

Comment: @Larnu OP is providing image for resultset `SELECT * FROM SalaryDetails.dbo.Salary` and he is expecting order. It won't happen. **[No Seatbelt – Expecting Order without ORDER BY](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/conor_cunningham_msft/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by/)**

Comment: That much isn't clear, from your comment or the OP's image though, @LukaszSzozda .

Comment: @Larnu Question is clear.OP thinks if he is using `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ORDER BY` then data is ordered. SQL represents unordered sets so there is no intrinsic order. The only way to ensure data to be sorted is by using explicit `ORDER BY` during retrieval.

Comment: Read this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/aeb1053d-0dc2-4dc3-96f5-8b213fed9669/insert-into-as-select-with-order-by?forum=transactsql

Comment: I know that @LukaszSzozda, but your inital comment just tells the OP to use `ORDER BY` in a `SELECT`. They *have* a `SELECT` and they *have* an `ORDER BY`; you don't make it clear in that comment that you mean in the retrieval, and hence my comment.

Comment: @Larnu OK, got it. Fair point. I will be more specific next time.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for the clarification. So is there any way on how to insert the records in ordered way from another table?

Comment: SQL Server will `INSERT` rows in whatever order it finds easiest, @Kirti . Having an `ORDER BY` in the `INSERT` only means that the value of an `IDENTITY` or `NEWSEQUENTIALID` will be in the order of the `ORDER BY`. After you `INSERT` data into a table the prior order by "lost", unless you have a way to determine it again by using an `ORDER BY` in the `SELECT` when you retrieve the data from the (new) table. SQL Server stores data in **unordered** heaps, not ordered sets; without an `ORDER BY` the data retried from a `SELECT` is completely arbitrary and just the order the DBMS "finds" it.

Comment: You are _inserting_ the rows in order (or at least generating IDENTITY values in order).  But you can't _observe_ the rows in order without a SELECT ... ORDER BY,

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the logic behind inserting data in particular order as you can order it during `select` anytime.

However, if the `order by` during insert is really concern, you can add clustered index on table (newly created) so that your actual data in the table `order by` based on clustered index `Columns`, try following query to do the same:

```
--Drop table SalaryDetails.dbo.SalaryAsc

SELECT * into SalaryDetails.dbo.SalaryAsc
FROM SalaryDetails.dbo.Salary as tb1
go

CREATE Clustered index CLU_SalaryAsc ON SalaryAsc (id asc);
```